# Spring Boot OAuth2 after login wrong redirect url

Tags: redirect, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Security and authentication is OAuth2.I have separated authentication, resource and front server. 
My problem is after logged in system can not redirect to main page or home page. its going to random image page like (localhost:7080/app/img/search.png)
But after logged in and than system redirect to random page, if i make request directly to main page localhost:7080/app/#/platform, its ok. it can open main page.
Access token and refresh token is exist and valid on MongoDB. I am not sure but it looks after logged in, front server or resource server can not redirect the user to the main page.
I dont know who is the responsible this redirection, Front-end configuration or front-end code ? Resource server config/code or authentication server ?
what should i see on DB when i check the access token and refresh token.
There is too much config code and file, i dont know how can I show all of them. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

In such situation browser network logs will help you.

After login check while redirecting from authentication server whether it has proper location in **Location** header.

If location is right as per the configuration then problem will be in client server else need to check in Authentication server.

Hope it will give proper direction to investigation.